# Can't find resources folder when right clicking on GoogleMaps.framework

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, google-maps

I've been following the directions for using the Google Maps SDK on iOS.

When I get to the step that says:

Right-click GoogleMaps.framework in your project, and select Show In Finder.

Drag the GoogleMaps.bundle from the Resources folder to your project. We suggest putting it in the Frameworks group. When prompted, ensure Copy items into destination group's folder is not selected.

I can't find the resources folder mentioned. When I selected "Show In Finder" for GoogleMaps.framework, the only things that show up are:

CHANGELOG
GoogleMaps.framework
GoogleMapsSDKDemos

Anyone know how I can get this "Resources" folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inbl,

After selecting "Show In Finder" for the GoogleMaps.framework, double click on the GoogleMaps.framework icon. You should then see a resources folder.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. (I didn't realize that was a folder...)